# how to speed up Matlab nested for loops when I cannot vectorize the calculations?

Tags: matlab

I have three big 3D arrays of the same size [41*141*12403], named in the Matlab code below alpha, beta and ni. From them I need to calculate another 3D array with the same size, which is obtained elementwise from the original matrices through a calculation that combines an infinite sum and definite integral calculations, using the value of each element. It therefore seems inevitible to have to use several nested loops to make this calculation. The code is already running now for several hours(!) and it is still in the first iteration of the outer loop (which needs to be performed 41 times!! According to my calculation, in this way the program will have to run more than two years!!!). I don't know how to optimize the code. Please help me !!

the code I use:

```
    z_len=size(KELDYSH_PARAM_r_z_t,1);   % 41 rows
    r_len=size(KELDYSH_PARAM_r_z_t,2);   % 141 columns   
    t_len=size(KELDYSH_PARAM_r_z_t,3);   % 12403 slices

    sumRes=zeros(z_len,r_len,t_len);

    for z_ind=1:z_len
        z_ind     % in order to track the advancement of the calculation
        for r_ind=1:r_len
            for t_ind=1:t_len
                sumCurrent=0;
                sumPrevious=inf;
                s=0;

                while abs(sumPrevious-sumCurrent)>1e-6
                    kapa=kapa_0+s;    %some scalar
                    x_of_w=(beta(z_ind,r_ind,t_ind).*(kapa-ni...
                       (z_ind,r_ind,t_ind))).^0.5;               
                    sumPrevious=sumCurrent;
                    sumCurrent=sumCurrent+exp(-alpha(z_ind,r_ind,t_ind).* ...
                        (kapa-ni(z_ind,r_ind,t_ind))).*(x_of_w.^(2*abs(m)+1)/2).* ...
                            w_m_integral(x_of_w,m);
                    s=s+1;
                end

                sumRes(z_ind,r_ind,t_ind)=sumCurrent;
            end
        end
    end
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function  res=w_m_integral(x_of_w,m)

    res=quad(@integrandFun,0,1,1e-6);

    function y=integrandFun(t)
            y=exp(-x_of_w^2*t).*t.^(abs(m))./((1-t).^0.5);
    end
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1 - more vectorising**

It's a pretty complex model you're working with and not all the terms are explained, but some parts can still be further vectorised. Your `alpha`, `beta` and `ni` matrices are presumably static and precomputed? Your `s` value is a scalar and `kapa` could be either, so you can probably precompute the x_of_w matrix all in one go too. This would give you a very slight speedup all on its own, though you'd be spending memory to get it - 71 million points is doable these days but will call for an awful lot of hardware. Doing it once for each of your 41 rows would reduce the burden neatly.

That leaves the integral itself. The `quad` function doesn't accept vector inputs - it would be a nightmare wouldn't it? - and neither does `integral`, which Mathworks are recommending you use instead. But if your integration limits are the same in each case then why not do the integral the old-fashioned way? Compute a matrix for the value of the integrand at 1, compute another matrix for the value of the integrand at 0 and then take the difference.

Then you can write a single loop that computes the integral for the whole input space then tests the convergence for all the matrix elements. Make a mask that notes the ones that have not converged and recalculate those with the increased `s`. Repeat until all have converged (or you hit a threshold for iterations).

**Option 2 - parallelise it**

It used to be the case that matlab was much faster with vectorised operations than loops. I can't find a source for it now but I think I've read that it's become a lot faster recently with `for` loops too, so depending on the resources you have available you might get better results by parallelising the code you currently have. That's going to need a bit of refactoring too - the big problems are overheads while copying in data to the workers (which you can fix by chopping the inputs up into chunks and just feeding the relevant one in) and the `parfor` loop not allowing you to use certain variables, usually ones which cover the whole space. Again chopping them up helps.

But if you have a 2 year runtime you will need a factor of at least 100 I'm guessing, so that means a cluster! If you're at a university or somewhere where you might be able to get a few days on a 500-core cluster then go for that...

If you can write the integral in a closed form then it might be amenable to GPU computation. Those things can do certain classes of computation very fast but you have to be able to parallelise the job and reduce the actual computation to something basic comprised mainly of addition and multiplication. The CUDA libraries have done a lot of the legwork and [matlab has an interface to them](http://uk.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html) so have a read about those.

**Option 3 - reduce the scope**

Finally, if neither of the above two results in sufficient speedups, then you may have to reduce the scope of your calculation. Trim the input space as much as you can and perhaps accept a lower convergence threshold. If you know how many iterations you tend to need inside the innermost `while` loop (the one with the `s` counter in it) then it might turn out that reducing the convergence criterion reduces the number of iterations you need, which could speed it up. The profiler can help see where you're spending your time.

The bottom line though is that 71 million points are going to take some time to compute. You can optimise the computation only so far, the odds are that for a problem of this size you will have to throw hardware at it.