# How to speed up a 3D nested loop to fill a (i,j,k)-matrix with indices from other arrays in Matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop

I have the following problem: given a 3D irregular geometry `A` with 
`(i,j,k)`-coordinates, which are the centroids of connected voxels, create a table with the `(i_out,j_out,k_out)`-coordinates of the cells that represent the complementary set `B` of the bounding box of `A`, which we may call `C`. That is to say, I need the voxel coordinates of the set `B = C - A`.

To get this done, I am using the Matlab code below, but it is taking too much time to complete when `C` is fairly large. Then, I would like to speed up the code. To make it clear: `cvc` is the matrix of voxel coordinates of `A`; `allcvc` should produce `C` and `B` results from `outcvc` after `setdiff`.

Someone has a clue regarding the code performance, or even to improve my strategy?

**Problem:** the for-loop seems to be the villain.

**My attempts:** I have tried to follow some hints of [Yair Altman's book](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/books/matlab-performance) by doing some `tic,toc` analyses, using pre-allocation and `int8` since I do not need `double` values. `deal` yet gave me a slight improvement with `min,max`. I have also checked this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027239/how-to-speed-up-matlab-nested-for-loops-when-i-cannot-vectorize-the-calculations), but, parallelism, for instance, is a limitation that I have for now.

```
% A bounding box limits
m = min(cvc,[],1); 
M = max(cvc,[],1);
[im,jm,km,iM,jM,kM] = deal(m(1),m(2),m(3),M(1),M(2),M(3));

% (i,j,k) indices of regular grid
I = im:iM;
J = jm:jM;
K = km:kM;

% (i,j,k) table 
m = length(I);
n = length(J);
p = length(K);
num = m*n*p;
allcvc = zeros(num,3,'int8');
for N = 1:num
    for i = 1:m
        for j = 1:n
            for k = 1:p
                aux = [I(i),J(j),K(k)];
                allcvc(N,:) = aux;
            end
        end
    end
end

% operation of exclusion: out = all - in
[outcvc,~] = setdiff(allcvc,cvc,'rows');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid all `for`-loops in the present code you can use `ndgrid` or `meshgrid` functions. For example

```
[I,J,K] = ndgrid(im:iM, jm:jM, km:kM);
allcvc = [I(:),J(:),K(:)];
```

instead of your code between `% (i,j,k) indices of regular grid` and `% operation of exclusion: out =`.

Comment: Gotcha! I had not realised that `ndgrid` could be a quick, prompt and clean solution to this! Thank you very much, Alexander Korovin! ;)

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow. If the answer helps, please "upvote it" (click on up-triangle) and maybe "accept it" (click on tickmark only you as OP see).

Comment: Hey, I had already "upvoted it", but it was only registered because I am less-15 reputation to have the score displayed. :)

Comment: No problems. It's just for information. Concerning MATLAB you should "think vectorized" (it's the slogan of MATLAB).

Comment: OK. I see! Thank you.

Comment: Sincere apologies, Alexander! I have really lost the pace. Done!